# SQL subbstr Negative starting position

Tags: sql, substring

Can someone please explain what the below piece of code is executing?

I know it is using the length of the symbol field as the number of characters to take. However, the negative 2 is confusing me. So, I'm not sure what it is executing.

```
substr(symbol,-2,length(symbol))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That usually means that it starts counting from the end -- if your database doesn't return an error.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking this but needed confirmation